# Is the rational curves passing through a point in Fano, Projective?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$
be a smooth projective Fano variety of dimension $n$ with Picard number one over the field of complex numbers and different from the projective space. We also assume that the tangent bundle of $X$ is not nef. Let $K$ be a component of the Hilbert scheme of rational curves in $X$ such that given any two point in $X$ there is a rational curve $C \in K$ joining them. Let $x$ be a general point in $X$. Let $K_x$ be the subvariety of $K$ consisting curves passing through $x$. Note that the curves in $K_x$ cover $X$.

Question: (1) Is $K_x$ projective ? (2) Can $TX\vert_C$ be ample for every $C \in K_x$ ?

Comment: "Let $K$ be a component of rational curves in $X$" — a component in what? The Hilbert scheme? Some moduli space of (stable?) rational curves? Something else?

Comment: A component of Hilbert scheme of rational curves in $X$.